# Fill down stopping at row 33

Tags: vba, excel

I have been back and forward with the below code for a couple of weeks now. There is little annoying things I can't quite suss. The latest oddity is fill down stopping at row 33, all be it I can't see a reason why.

Code:

```
Sub ButtonMacro()
'Hide alerts
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Save to users device
    ChDir "U:\WINDOWS"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\WINDOWS\OrderForm.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Create new workbook and populate
    Workbooks.Add
    Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "MSG"
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[4]"
    Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "1400008000"
    Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "501346009175"
    Range("F1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("G1").FormulaR1C1 = "=Now()"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "HDR"
    Range("B2").FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("C2").FormulaR1C1 = "1400011281"
    Range("G2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[-1]"
    Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[2]C[-4]"
    Range("K2").FormulaR1C1 = "STD"
    Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R5C2"
    Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R7C2"
    Range("O2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R8C2"
    Range("Q2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R9C2"
    Range("R2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R12C2"
    Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "POS"
    Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = "=ROW()*10-20"
    Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!r[12]c"
    Range("D3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!r[12]c[-3]"
    Range("E3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!r[12]c[-3]"
    Range("F3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!r[12]c[-1]"
    Range("G3").FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!r[12]c"
    Range("H3").FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1]="""",""0"",""GBP"")"
    Range("M3").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3], ""POS"")+COUNTIF(C[-3], ""HDR"")"

'Fills column to last row of data from Cell C3
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("C3:H3" & LastRow).FillDown


'Find last blank in C and fill with TRA  
    Cells(Application.Evaluate("MAX(IF(C3:C2000<>"""",ROW(c3:c2000)),0,1)"), "C").Select
    ActiveCell = "TRA"

'Format cells to remove 0 value
    Range("A1:Z1000").Select
    Range("Z1000").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "#;#;"

'Reinstate alerts
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "We have saved a copy of your order form to your computer at C:\X\X"
End Sub
```

This is the post script formatting. The TRA should populate the last blank cell but it is finding the formulas hence populating midsheet. So this poses me two questions. 1 Why is it stopping after 15 rows, and how do I get it to ignore the formula in the other rows?. I do third by the by question that I haven't yet looked at is offsetting the the final row to start populating at AX (the last row equal to the last populated row/cell of c). I'm happy to keep looking into that if it's too much for one thread.

[image]

And this is what the form looks like before hand. The gray "Create order file" button being where the macro will sit.

[image]

So there is two lines of gumpf, not actual title lines, but these will always remain the same:

- Row 1: Order info (dates etc)
- Row 2: Ship to and orderer info
- Row 3: Requested parts (these should populate down), including the following rows which are quantity and cost etc
- Row x: A total of the populated rows

Thanks as always in advance.

Comment: Rossco you are hardcoding too much imho :/

Comment: @Simo I'm not a massive coder. I get by on what I know and muddle through the rest, so elaborate for me. It is very much x=y so not much ambiguity, but if there is a better way of doing what I've done, let me know. Would hard coding possibly have an effect on the fill down stopping at a certain row?

Comment: Hardcoding something could lead to an error like that. Too many things to take into mind.

Comment: Try to create a data table or a data set and put your values inside, than use it to populate your excel sheet.

Comment: @Simo I'll give it a go. For me my logic is that there is nothing that references that cell/row (even from a relative reference). So how would it get there? (I appreciate you may not be able to explain why an error is the way it is). Surely building a table and referencing certain areas on the table is hard coding but putting a table in the middle of it? So effectively a step even further. As I said I muddle by so these are probably really stupid questions, but if I don't know I don't know.

Comment: Hardcoding values inside a data table could help for the following reasons: You can always know where is the last cell written (because you know exactly how many rows and columns your data table has.), the excel worksheet will be filled programmatically inside 2 loops (outer loop for the rows, inner loop for the columns) and you can delcare the loop until last row and last column. This will help alot during the debug and might solve itself the problem

Comment: there is a possibility that hardcoding every single value gives you a problem because you forgot something. If it doesn't solve anything, at least you have a clear and more readable code ;)

Comment: can you edit the code in order to add a comment on the line the gives you the error? can you include the error message on your question?

Comment: @Simo , again apologies if this is a stupid question. But edit in what way to put what text where? It already inserts TRA. Everything completes absolutely fine at present, I get no errors, just that it doesn't like to fill down, and that it won't ignore formula. I am a complete noob at this so sorry if this is like educating a small child.  Happy to move to chat to prevent the thread becoming busy if needs be?

Comment: you don't have enough rep to start a chat. By the way. Debug your code line by line, and tell me where the program stops to fill your excel ;)

Comment: Ah No worries, I'm guessing this is something to do with my code as well, but I can't debug. As soon as I get to "'Save to users device
    ChDir "U:\WINDOWS"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\WINDOWS\OrderForm.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False" it creates the new form and debug stops. I then can't run it as it picks up the open doc with the same name. You are probably shaking your head in anger and frustration now. Sorry!.

Comment: I'm a bit confused to be honest

Comment: You and me both. As soon as it saves the file to U:\ it creates it. At that stage I can't debug, if I step into it it auto creates the form. And as the formula work it gives no errors at all. I am going back through all of the references now. But if they are all right a table may be the only way. My only issues is then that due to the number of fields the table will be massive.

Comment: @Simo would I be better off creating four smaller tables for each of the respective rows. Or one large table?.

Comment: Imagine that your table is an excel sheet and fill it using this logic. You can also add in the header of the data table the columns' name. You can read more about data tables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.datatable(object))

Comment: @Simo, you're a star. I'll go through and put it into a table and see where I get to. Thanks for all of the help so far.